# Пустой экран при запуске

Tags: canvas, java, j2me

Никак разобраться не могу. Все компилируется нормально, на выходе должен нарисоваться график функции, но при запуске пустой экран.

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;

public class GraphTest extends MIDlet {

    private Display display;

    public void pauseApp() {
    }
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
    public void startApp() {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        display.getDisplay(this);
        display.setCurrent(graph);
    }
}

class Graph extends Canvas {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int width = g.getClipWidth();
        int height = g.getClipHeight();
        g.setColor(255, 0, 0);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(0, 0, 0);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
        g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
        g.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
        g.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
        g.setColor(255, 0, 0);
        for (int x = -width / 2; x < width / 2; x++) {
            int y = -x * x / 40;
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

По графике из книги "Е.Буткевич Пишем программы и игры для сот. телефонов".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поправь:

```
display=Display.getDisplay(this);
```

А Буткевича выкин...

Comment: j2me - это не какой-то там мейнстрим андроид =)

Comment: Да ладно тебе - лет 5 назад это был мейнстрим, да еще какой...